# Считывание информации из второй таблицы

Tags: android, android-sqlite, cursoradaper

Здравствуйте, у меня возник вопрос, почему я могу считать информацию только из одной базы данных, а вторая как будто и не создавалась. В моем приложении пользователь нажимает на CardView в ResyclerView и в интенте передается номер нажатой позиции. Так вот когда пользователь нажимает на первый элемент в ResyclerView все работает, как только он нажимает на второй пункт студия пишет ошибку: SQLiteException: no such table: AUTORATE. И если при старте приложения сразу нажать на второй пункт, то считывания тоже не произойдет. 
Класс в котором создается БД :

```
public class MyDataBase {

private DBOpenHelper dbOpenHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase database;

private static final String DB_NAME = "AutoRate";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "AUTOCOLOR";
private static final String SECOND_TABLE_NAME = "AUTORATE";

public static final String NAME = "NAME";
public static final String DESCRIPTION = "DESCRIPTION";
public static final String PRICE = "PRICE";


private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

public MyDataBase(Context context) {
    dbOpenHelper = new DBOpenHelper(context);
}


public Cursor getAllItems(String tableName) {
    database = dbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    return database.query(tableName, null, null, null, null, null, null);
}

public void close() {
    if (dbOpenHelper != null) dbOpenHelper.close();
    if (database != null) database.close();
}
public class DBOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + SECOND_TABLE_NAME + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + NAME + " TEXT, "
                + DESCRIPTION + " TEXT, "
                + PRICE + " INTEGER) ;");
        insertService(db, "AUTORATE", "Шиномонтаж", "Замена четырех колес", 5000);
        insertService(db, "AUTORATE", "Кузовные работы", "Замена чего то там", 12000);
        insertService(db, "AUTORATE", "Диагностика", "Продиагностировать чего-нибудь", 4000);

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + NAME + " TEXT, "
                + DESCRIPTION + " TEXT, "
                + PRICE + " INTEGER) ;");
        insertService(db, "AUTOCOLOR", "Шиномонтаж", "Замена четырех колес", 4000);
        insertService(db, "AUTOCOLOR", "Кузовные работы", "Замена чего то там", 10000);
        insertService(db, "AUTOCOLOR", "Диагностика", "Продиагностировать чего-нибудь", 3000);



    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    private void insertService(SQLiteDatabase db, String currentDataBaseName, String name, String description, int price) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(DESCRIPTION, description);
        contentValues.put(PRICE , price);
        db.insert(currentDataBaseName, null, contentValues);
    }
}
```

}
Код, где из интента достается номер нажатой позиция на ResyclerView:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_auto_service_detail);
    Bundle bundle= getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle != null){
        Object o = bundle.get(EXTRA_SERVICE_NO);
        autoServiceNo = (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(o)));
    }
    tableName = AutoServiceInfo.autoServices[autoServiceNo].getName();
    dataBase = new MyDataBase(this);
    Cursor cursor = dataBase.getAllItems(tableName);

    String[]from = new String[]{MyDataBase.NAME,MyDataBase.DESCRIPTION,MyDataBase.PRICE};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.tvName, R.id.tvDescription, R.id.tvPrise};


    cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, cursor, from, to,0);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewPrise);
    listView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

Comment: Вторую таблицу добавили позже (после первого запуска)? При изменении структуры увеличивайте DB_VERSION, и в onUpgrade сначала дропните все таблице, потом создайте заново. (см. любой туториал по DataBaseHelper)

Comment: в принципе при  разработке  и отладке не обязательно гонять БД по увеличению версий и использованию onUpgrade. Достаточно просто удалить приложение с устройства, на котором проводится тестирование его же инструментами. В таком случае будет удалена и сама БД. И с новой установкой будет создана новая. Если же не удалять приложение а только перезаливать,  то БД будет оставаться без изменений.

Comment: Вторую таблицу добавили позже (после первого запуска)? Да, после запуска. сейчас попробую сделать, что вы посоветовали

Comment: О даааа. Спасибо вам большое. заработало )))))